# Why did I get such a low swap return on Uniswap?

Tags: uniswap

I used Uniswap router to swap ether for Unisocks, but when I check the transactions details [0xfcba19d84b4f578fcff1dc2378b673af1c5fa54e422555f27fd2ac6b46fc21ae](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfcba19d84b4f578fcff1dc2378b673af1c5fa54e422555f27fd2ac6b46fc21ae), I'm getting much less $SOCK's than what I paid for.

[image]

The screenshot above shows I'm only get about $94 dollars worth of Unisocks when I paid 1 ether, and this tx was on Jul-25-2021.

I set the slippage to 50 basis points(0.5%).

Does anybody know why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always check price and slippage before signing a swap.**

Check price, because it might be off. (For example, someone might have bought a huge amount just before you, causing the price to rise too high.)

Check slippage, because there might not be enough liquidity in the pool.